# K8s Issue connecting to Cassandra on Mac OS (via Node.js)

Tags: node.js, cassandra, kubernetes, minikube

While trying to setup Cassandra database in a local Kubernetes cluster on a Mac OS (via Minikube), I am getting connection issues. 
It seems like Node.js is not able to resolve DNS settings correctly, but resolving via command line DOES work.

The setup is as following (simplified):
Cassandra Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9042
      targetPort: 9042
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: cassandra
```

In addition, there's a PersistentVolume and a StatefulSet.

The application itself is very basic

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/acme/app1
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3003
```

And a service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: app1
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3003
      targetPort: 3003
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
```

there also a simple ingress setup

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.acme.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 3003
```

And added to `/etc/hosts` the minikube ip address

```
192.xxx.xx.xxx dev.acme.com
```

So far so good.

When trying to call `dev.acme.com/app1` via Postman, the node.js app itself is being called correctly (can see in the logs), HOWEVER, the app can not connect to Cassandra and times out with the following error:

> "All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried,
>   92.242.140.2:9042: DriverError: Connection timeout. See innerErrors."

The IP `92.242.140.2` seems to be just a public IP that is related to my ISP, I believe since the app is not able to resolve the service name.

I created a simple node.js script to test dns:

`var dns = require('dns')
dns.resolve6('cassandra', (err, res) => console.log('ERR:', err, 'RES:', res))`

and the response is

> ERR: { Error: queryAaaa ENOTFOUND cassandra
>       at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:197:19)   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',   code: 'ENOTFOUND',   syscall: 'queryAaaa',   hostname:
>   'cassandra' } RES: undefined

However, and this is where it gets confusing - when I ssh into the pod (app1), I am able to connect to cassandra service using:

`cqlsh cassandra 9042 --cqlversion=3.4.4`

So it seems as the pod is "aware" of the service name, but node.js runtime is not.

Any idea what could cause the node.js to not being able to resolve the service name/dns settings?

**UPDATE**

After re-installing the whole cluster, including re-installing docker, kubectl and minikube I am getting the same issue.

While running `ping cassandra` from app1 container via ssh, I am getting the following

> PING cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local (10.96.239.137) 56(84) bytes
>   of data. 64 bytes from cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
>   (10.96.239.137): icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=27.0 ms
>
> 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms

Which seems to be fine.
However, when running from Node.js runtime I am still getting the same error -

> "All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried,
>   92.242.140.2:9042: DriverError: Connection timeout. See innerErrors."

These are the services

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
app1        ClusterIP   None            <none>        3003/TCP         11m
cassandra    NodePort    10.96.239.137   <none>        9042:32564/TCP   38h
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          38h
```

And these are the pods (all namespaces)

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       app1-85d889db5-m977z                       1/1     Running   0          2m1s
default       cassandra-0                                 1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   calico-etcd-ccvs8                           1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   calico-node-thzwx                           2/2     Running   0          38h
kube-system   calico-policy-controller-5bb4fc6cdc-cnhrt   1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-z8pr4                    1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-zcn6p                    1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   default-http-backend-5ff9d456ff-84zb5       1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   etcd-minikube                               1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube                 1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube                     1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube            1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   kube-proxy-jj7c4                            1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube                     1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-ccc79bfc9-6jtgq        1/1     Running   4          38h
kube-system   nginx-ingress-controller-7c66d668b-rvxpc    1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   registry-creds-x5bhl                        1/1     Running   0          38h
kube-system   storage-provisioner                         1/1     Running   0          38h
```

**UPDATE 2**

The code to connect to Cassandra from Node.js:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['cassandra:9042'], localDataCenter: 'datacenter1', keyspace: 'auth_server' });

const query = 'SELECT * FROM user';
client.execute(query, [])
  .then(result => console.log('User with email %s', result.rows[0].email));
```

It DOES work when replacing `cassandra:9042` with `10.96.239.137:9042` (10.69.239.137 is the ip address received from pinging cassandra via cli).

Comment: You can check out the driver logs for more information of what's happening under the hood: https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#logging

Comment: @jorgebg thanks, it gibes the same error in the logs `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 92.242.140.2:9042. See innerErrors.`

Comment: can you please post the node.js code initializing the Cassandra driver?

Comment: @kellanburket thanks, updated.

Comment: and `dns.resolve6` is still throwing a not found error for cassandra?

Comment: @kellanburket exactly, it returns `ENOTFOUND` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cassandra driver for Node.js uses `resolve4`/`resolve6` to do its dns lookup, which bypasses your `resolv.conf` file. A program like ping uses resolv.conf to resolve 'cassandra' to 'cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local', the actual dns name assigned to your Cassandra service. For a more detailed explanation of name resolution in node.js see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985367/node-js-dns-resolve-vs-dns-lookup).

The fix is simple, just pass in the full service name to your client:

```
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local:9042'], localDataCenter: 'datacenter1', keyspace: 'auth_server' });
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves it! Do you know if it's the normal behavior or is there something different in my setup that requires the full service name? Since I haven't seen any mention of it in the documentation

Comment: it seems to be normal behavior related to the node.js Cassandra driver

Comment: Cassandra-driver falls back to `dns.lookup` if `dns.resolve*` doesn't return any address. So normally it should work in Kubernetes with setting service name in `contactPoints`. In this case the DNS did resolve the service name but gave an invalid IP 92.242.140.2 then caused the failure. Need to check what's wrong in DNS configuration.